# french and english quotes in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Is it possible to have in bibliography:
english quotes in english references and
french quotes in french references?

Thank you for your help!

jobonne

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will! In this instance it would be helpful it you provided some references.

Comment: Please provide the MWE as suggested by @Andrew but also please provide some relevant bibliography entries.

Comment: Yes it is possible if you are using biblatex and if the bib contains the correct langid field.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `biblatex` and `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english=british, french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, babel =other]{biblatex}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
AUTHOR = "John Doe",
TITLE = "My article",
JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
VOLUME = "16",
YEAR = "2005",
LANGID ="english"}
@article{myfrenchart,
AUTHOR = "Jean Martin",
TITLE = "Mon Article à la noix",
JOURNALTITLE = "Un Journal à la coule",
VOLUME = "12",
YEAR = "2008",
LANGID ="french"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]